# Wavelet choice for wav file analysis

Tags: python, time-series

### Context

I am working on the Maestro v3.0 dataset https://magenta.tensorflow.org/datasets/maestro#v300 to familiarize myself with signal processing. Years ago, I mainly worked on image processing with CNNs. Here, I have an association of midi files with **stereo wav files**. What I am trying to achieve is fairly simple: note envelope identification, maybe some chord recognition.

### Choice of the proper wavelet function

I need to reduce the length of the structure I will feed my NN with. I read that, one of the best way to so is to apply wavelet functions. Because of the size of the dataset, I will stick to **Discrete Wavelet functions** (DWF). I do have a general understanding of how wavelet functions work, what I struggle with is the number of available functions in [pywavelets](https://pywavelets.readthedocs.io): I just don't know what is relevant for music processing. Here are the families

- Haar (haar)
- Daubechies (db)
- Symlets (sym)
- Coiflets (coif)
- Biorthogonal (bior)
- Reverse biorthogonal (rbio)
- “Discrete” FIR approximation of Meyer wavelet (dmey)
- Gaussian wavelets (gaus)
- Mexican hat wavelet (mexh)
- Morlet wavelet (morl)
- Complex Gaussian wavelets (cgau)
- Shannon wavelets (shan)
- Frequency B-Spline wavelets (fbsp)
- Complex Morlet wavelets (cmor)

Because of the typical shape of a piano note envelope, based on the [shape of the wavelet functions](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/gs/introduction-to-the-wavelet-families.html), I would:

- include: db, bior, sym
- exclude: mexh, morl, dmey because of their axial symmetry and continuity

But I just don't know what to do with the rest

### Proper treatment of stereo

The wave files contain the stereo record of one piano. I can

```py
sampling_frequency, signal = scipy.io.wavfile.read(wave_file)
approx, detail = pywt.dwt(signal, "db1", axis=0)
```

and, for a `signal` of shape (40110639, 2), I get a `detail` of shape (20055320, 2).

Am I on the right track?